# How to solve Value Error with regards to CNN training

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

ISSUE:

So I have this error that happens when my I try to train my cnn.

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (32,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

And I don't know what it means. this code btw is not 100% mine I just took a CNN code and modified it to make it apply to what I need. 
Although my knowledge with CNN coding is very limited and I have no proper training to Python programming as well.

Can someone explain to me what is going on with the error and I want to know what is causing it. And can you guys tell me if what I did so far on the code is correct?

I plan to create a CNN that will be able to classify an image to contain either sexual, violence, horror, drugs content. So this is a multi class CNN with an image input and the output would be classifying the category the image belongs.

Here is the rest of the CNN code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

IMAGE_LENGHT = 300
EPOCH_COUNT = 10
MODEL_PATH = 'model.hdf5'
WEIGHTS_PATH = 'weights.hdf5'

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (9, 9),  input_shape = (IMAGE_LENGHT,IMAGE_LENGHT, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (9, 9), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (9, 9), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['binary_accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'TRAIN_SET',
        target_size = (IMAGE_LENGHT,IMAGE_LENGHT),
        batch_size = 100,
        class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'TEST_SET',
        target_size = (IMAGE_LENGHT,IMAGE_LENGHT),
        batch_size = 100,
        class_mode = 'binary')

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(WEIGHTS_PATH, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
model.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=60,
        epochs = EPOCH_COUNT,
        validation_data = test_set,
        validation_steps =20,
        callbacks = [checkpoint])
model.save(MODEL_PATH, True, True)
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your last layer has shape 32 while it should be one, try add one more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause are here

```
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'softmax'))
```

and here

```
class_mode = 'binary'
```

What cause the error is your model needs the output shape to be `(batch_size, 32)` but by `class_mode = 'binary'` you got only `(batch_size, 1)`.

First, you need to know how many classes your images are, how many folder in `TRAIN_SET` in this case, and put it to the `Dense()`. Like if you have 7 classes then it'll like this

```
model.add(Dense(7, activation = 'softmax'))
```

and change `class_mode = 'binary'` to `class_mode = 'categorical'`. For multi-classes classification you can't label like `0` is dog `1` is cat `2` is duck and `3` is horse, you can't cut a duck by half and get a cat or minus a horse by a horse and get a dog. You need a `one-hot` encoding.

Second, about the `binary` classes, if your data is only 2 classes like cat and dog then you can just have the model answer like "is this image a dog" then if it's true it's a dog or if it's false it's a cat.

In this case you can use

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))  # beware, it's 'sigmoid' here, not 'softmax'
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])  # binary_crossentropy here, not categorical
```

and

```
class_mode = 'binary'
```

## Edit

[One hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) is like, lets define drugs=0, horror=1, violence=2, and sexual=3, if the answer is `violence` then the target data will be `[0, 0, 1, 0]`. The model will predict like `[0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.05]`, probability of each class instead of the actual number 2. Like I said, you cannot add `horror` with `violence` and get `sexual` as result so you need to define them separately, have the model predict what the most-likely class here.

## Edit 2

Binary accuracy is being use when each of your image can be more than 1 class, like Emma Watson can be both actress, person or woman, neither classes are wrong. The out put might be like `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`, summation doesn't need to be 1. But in your case here it's a `categorical classification`, not `binary`, each image generate from `flow_from_directory` will be labeled as `categorical` if you want it to be multi-class, you can still use `binary_accuracy` and get the same result but it's not for this purpose, someone might scratch their head when reading your code later so I think use `accuracy` here is a better idea.

Comment: Thanks I am starting to understand the problem, though I would like to know what one - hot encoding means? And do you mean by classes is the number of categories the images have? like in my case, I have four classifications which are drugs, horror, violence, and sexual images. So that means the value I will apply on the Dense part is 4? Am I correct?

Comment: In your case, use `Dense(4` is correct. Added answer of other question in the main answer

Comment: I see now thank you for the info. This is helping me a lot. but I do have one more question. In the model.compile code part, are the given parameters I used are correct? like for example the optimizer, loss and metrics I used are they the right values to use in my case?

Comment: I think `metrics=['binary_accuracy']` is questionable, it's might not cause error but use only `metrics='accuracy'` is better here(someone will definitely ask you why use this if you show them the code). It's not wrong but not quite correct.

Comment: Optimizer is a bit tricky, it always runs no matter what you use but result will be different, you need to find which is the best for your data. But it's OK with just `'adam'` or `'rmsprop'`, `sgd` needs `momentum` so it'll be `keras.optimizers.sgd(0.01, 0.9)`

Comment: BTW, you really NEED a bigger model. See https://keras.io/applications

Comment: And `ImageDataGenerator` can augment your data as well, something like `horizontal_flip` might help improve accuracy a lot.

Comment: The images used as dataset are preprocessed. We did the augmented part there with the flipping and normalizing and saved the output images in a folder. then fed those images to the cnn. So the cnn would not need to preprocess the images but just train right away

Comment: That's OK, but don't forget to change your model, right now it's way too small, it won't give a good result even with easy task like `Cifar`.

Answer (score 0):

Your last layer has 32 units and you are using softmax. So you are supposed to have more than 2 classes. The neural net expects a target of 32 dimensions, so you will have to one-hot encode your target shape (1,) by doing:

```
import pandas as pd
y_train=pd.get_dummies(target)
```

After that, check data dimensionality (number of classes) by running:

```
y_train.shape[1]
```

This output dimension is the number of classes you have in your target variable. So you will have:

```
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation = 'softmax'))
```

I would also change:

```
metrics = ['accuracy']
```

If you indeed have a binary target, last layer should be:

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

In this case, you should also one-hot encode your target variable to `(batch_size,number_classes)`.